# c++ hello world program in hypertable

Tags: c++, hypertable

i couldn't find an simple hello world program that inserts data into hypertable database ... and for retrieving too....can any one explain with an simple example??

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/hypertable/wiki/ArchitecturalOverview#C++_Client_API has two examples: one to insert records and one to retrieve them.